# phpmyadmin error 404.0 with xampp

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

how can I fix this error? when I connect to apache, it's stop working. when I try to click admin on mysql and the browser is open ( localhost/phpmyadmin/ ) and I get this message "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found . resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: have you started Apache?

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the default port number from 80 to e.g 7000 & permissions for the folder.

Good luck & hope this helps.